# Loading thousand of files in same memory chunk C

Tags: c

Box: Linux, gcc.

Problem :

Finding out the file signature of an home folder, which contains thousand of items, by scanning this folder recursively.

Done so far:

Using `mmap()` system call to load the first 1k byte of each file and check the file magic number.
The drawback with that method is that for each file encountered i've got to make two system calls (e.g `mmap()` and `munmap()`).

Best solution if possible:

I would like to allocate a single chunk of memory, load each file (in a row) in this unique buffer and when processing is completed deallocate it, meaning that for each folder scanned i would only use two system calls.

I can't figure out which system call to use in order to achieve that, not even if this solution is realistic!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why? What are you actually trying to accomplish? What's the end goal here?

Comment: `I've got to make two system calls (e.g mmap and munmap).` You actually need four: open() and close() are needed as well.

Comment: It's the disk that is the bottleneck not the number of system calls.

Comment: To read N files you need 3xN calls. One `fopen()`, `fread()` and  `fclose()` for each file. You can not do it with fewer calls. Additionally you need one `malloc()` and one `free()`.

Comment: My goal is to allocate a unique chunk of memory, use this buffer to load 1k of each file found in a folder,meaning reusing the same adress (space allocated) to map them in memory. So far for each file encountered i made a mmap call.

Comment: and this mmap call, i believe, allocate memory at different address for each file processed(if i'm not wrong). In fact i would like to allocate once and reuse that space..

Comment: You'll need **at least three** syscalls per file : open+read+close. After checksumming the read buffer could be used again for the next file. (in line# 42)

Comment: @wildplaster I got your point.I'll try your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about performance until you know it isn't enough. Your time is much more valuable than the gains in program run time (except for extremely rare cases). And when the performance isn't enough, *measure* before digging in. There are numerous war stories on "performance optimizations" that were a complete waste (if not positivley harmful).